# sails beforeUpdate doesn't contains the object Id

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I need to add some condition to beforeUpdate, sending to a specific event only if certain property was updated, and need to know its previous value.
I need the object Id to do that, but it is not appears in beforeUpdate values. How can I know the object id?

```
beforeUpdate(values, cb) {
    // if another field was updated except of the lastActive field
    if (values.length > 1) {
      const id = this.update.arguments[0];
      // id is undefined now. how can I get user id?
      const oldUser = User.findOne({id: values.id});
      // because I need to know user old values in sendUser function
      myFunction.sendUser(oldUser);
     }
    cb();
 }
```

Comment: why do you need object id in before update? you may not need it. And if you need it you can use afterUpdate lifecycle method.
Can you explain your requirement?

Comment: when user is updated, I invoke specific event and send his old email as parameter - so I need his id in order to get the old email value. However, I don't want to raise the event in case that only lastActive field was updated, because it is being updated whenever the user enters the application.

Comment: can you show the code snippet? how you are calling it?